# Can't add myself to group

Tags: permissions, groups

Getting into arduino and followed the instructions at: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux

Since I'm having issues writing to the serial port, I did the following as instructed (my username is thomas):

`ls -l /dev/ttyACM*`

which returned

`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Nov 11 08:57 /dev/ttyACM0`

so then I wanted to add myself to the group dialout. Per instructions:

`sudo usermod -a -G dialout thomas`

then I typed `groups`:

`thomas adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker`

Logging back in made no difference.

Dug for a while found out something about newgrp on stackeoverflow. Running that seemed to add me to the group, but didn't fix my issue. Logged out and back in and no longer member of the group.

```
thomas@bravos:~$ grep thomas /etc/group
adm:x:4:syslog,thomas
dialout:x:20:thomas
cdrom:x:24:thomas
sudo:x:27:thomas
dip:x:30:thomas
plugdev:x:46:thomas
lpadmin:x:120:thomas
lxd:x:131:thomas
thomas:x:1000:
sambashare:x:132:thomas
docker:x:1002:thomas
```

shows me as part of the list.

WTF???

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting seems to have fixed the problem. Evidently logging out and in is not sufficient.

Comment: the groups are not updated in a running session, this is right. Relogin would be enough, but your reboot is also good. For a one-time execution, there also is `sg`. It is similar to su, but for groups `sg -dialout -c "any command"`